# 404 Error when TFS 2010 Sends SOAP Alert to a WCF 4.0 Service

Tags: wcf, soap, tfs

I'm trying to write a WCF 4.0 service that will receive SOAP alerts from TFS 2010. Here is my service contract:

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03")]
 public interface IService1
 {
        [OperationContract(Action = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03/Notify")]
        [XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document)]
        void Notify(string eventXml, string tfsIdentityXml);
 }
```

I am using this binding configuration for my service endpoint:

```
 <bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
   <binding name="noSecurity">
    <security mode="None"/>
   </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding >
 </bindings>
```

Having registered a TFS alert using BISSUBSCRIBE.EXE and pointed it to my service, every time it is triggered my service is not invoked and instead I see the following in the TfsJobAgent log:

```
 Notification not delivered.
 Notification: WorkItemChangedEvent (DeliveryType: Soap; Address: http://192.168.10.10/TrafficLight/Service1.svc)
 Exception: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException: Team Foundation services are not available from server http://192.168.10.10/TrafficLight/Service1.svc.  Technical information (for administrator):
 HTTP code 404: Not Found ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
  at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.AsyncWebRequest.ExecRequest(Object obj)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.ProcessHttpResponse(HttpWebResponse response, Stream responseStream, WebException webException, XmlReader& xmlResponseReader)
  at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.ExecWebServiceRequest(HttpWebRequest request, XmlWriter requestXml, String methodName, HttpWebResponse& response)
  at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.JobService.Extensions.Core.TeamFoundationNotificationClient.Notify(String eventXml, String tfsIdentityXml, Subscription subscription)
  at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.JobService.Extensions.Core.NotificationJobExtension.SendSoapNotification(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationNotification notification, TeamFoundationIdentityService identityService)
```

(This is taken from the [Tfs_Configuration].[dbo].[tbl_JobHistory] table of my TFS 2010 installation)

Oddly enough, when I try my service's URL in internet explorer on the same machine where the TfsJobAgent is running, I receive the standard "You have created a service." web page auto-generated by WCF and *not* a 404 error.

At last, my question: *Why is the TFS Job Agent receiving a 404 error from my service which seems to be properly configured? How can I resolve this issue?*

Update: I've tried rewriting my service as an ASMX web service and it's working well. Below is the implementation. I still want to learn how to achieve the same using WCF 4.0 so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
 [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
 [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
 public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
 {
  [SoapDocumentMethod("http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03/Notify", RequestNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03")]
  [WebMethod]
  public void Notify(string eventXml, string tfsIdentityXml)
  {
   // log incoming event...
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created this succesfully - http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/08/02/How-to-use-WCF-to-subscribe-to-the-TFS-2010-Event-Service-rolling-up-hours.aspx - and it seems that you are using the same steps.

Did you also specify the wsHttpBinding for the endpoint?

Comment: Hi Ewald. Thanks so much for the tutorial - I've relied on it to get where I am. Regarding wsHttpBinding - I've tried both that and basicHttpBinding to no avail :|

Comment: I've gone over your tutorial again Ewald, tried wsHttpBinding with security mode set to None and now it's working. Thank you!