# Team Foundation Services are not available from server

Tags: tfs

OK, I hate to reopen a previously solved case, but I can't get it to work. I have two endpoints listening to events from TFS 2010 event service, one build with Web Service (ASMX) and one with WCF (SVC). The first one works fine. The second causes TFS to raise this error

```
HistoryId          : 4643911
EndTime            : 4/12/2013 11:40:31 AM
ResultMessage      : There were errors or warnings during notification delivery.

                     0/0 emails delivered.
                     1/2 soap notifications delivered. 
                     1 errors.
                     0 warnings.

                     -------------------------------
                     Notification not delivered.

                     Notification: WorkItemChangedEvent (DeliveryType: Soap; Address: http://[removed]/[removed]/Services/TfsListener.svc)

                     Exception: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException: Team Foundation services are not available from server 
                     http://[removed]/[removed]/Services/TfsListener.svc.
                     Technical information (for administrator):
                       HTTP code 404: Not Found ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
                        at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
                        at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.AsyncWebRequest.ExecRequest(Object obj)
                        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                        at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.ProcessHttpResponse(HttpWebResponse response, Stream responseStream, WebException webException, 
                     XmlReader& xmlResponseReader)
                        at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.ExecWebServiceRequest(HttpWebRequest request, XmlWriter requestXml, String methodName, 
                     HttpWebResponse& response)
                        at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.JobService.Extensions.Core.TeamFoundationNotificationClient.Notify(String eventXml, String tfsIdentityXml, Subscription subscription)
                        at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.JobService.Extensions.Core.NotificationJobExtension.SendSoapNotification(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, 
                     TeamFoundationNotification notification, TeamFoundationIdentityService identityService)

JobSource          : d9ee5b23-4aa4-4768-a7fb-4db33ab686d0
JobId              : a4804dcf-4bb6-4109-b61c-e59c2e8a9ff7
QueueTime          : 4/12/2013 11:40:29 AM
ExecutionStartTime : 4/12/2013 11:40:30 AM
AgentId            : 917eb9ee-2622-455c-a6e6-a1c96eeb1666
Result             : PartiallySucceeded
```

I have followed every advice I could find, including, [404 Error when TFS 2010 Sends SOAP Alert to a WCF 4.0 Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116851/404-error-when-tfs-2010-sends-soap-alert-to-a-wcf-4-0-service) and http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/08/02/How-to-use-WCF-to-subscribe-to-the-TFS-2010-Event-Service-rolling-up-hours.aspx.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it work. Here is what is missing from some of the websites out there:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="EventServiceBehavior" name="FullSvcClassName">
   <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EventServiceBinding"
             contract="FullSvcInterfaceName" />
</service>
```

If name of the service will not match your full class name (including namespace), you will get a basicHttpBinding and it will not work.
If you put anything in the endpoint address, like a relative address I thought I should provide, it will get appended to the and of the URI and fail.

I used WcfTestClient.exe and Fiddler2 to track it down. Enjoy!